# How to include a subdirectory of libraries in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm writing a Lambda function (in Python3 for this example) that requires two non-standard libraries. Those libraries in turn require ~30 additional libraries. To add those two directories locally to push to AWS Lambda I run the command `pip3 install <library> -t ./`.

Unfortunately now, I have all of these libraries and my lambda_handler.py all in the same directory. Now this *technically* works, but doesn't look good and is difficult for source control/readability/editing. I tried putting the libraries into a single directory, but then my python script is unable to find them.

Ideally, I'd like my entire Lambda project to look like this

*function.zip*

```
lambda_handler.py
config.py
libraries/
```

What would I need to do to my code/directory to have this sort of nice, clean structure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to ensure cleaner and nice structure of your deployment package, would be to use lambda [layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) for the dependencies:

> With layers, you can use libraries in your function **without needing to include them in your deployment package**.

This also allows you to **reuse** the same dependencies across multiple lambda functions, which is **beneficial** for source control, readability and maintainability of your lambda functions.

Comment: I have been utilizing AWS Lambdas on most of my serverless projects for over two years now and I am embarrassed that I never learned of this. Thank you so much for bringing this to my attention. This is exactly the answer I needed.